# Lightbox won't move/scroll WITH page

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, css-position, lightbox

Here is my test page - http://mymsaa.org/lightbox_test/2.php

I can use my scrollbar when the lightbox pops up but I NEED the lightbox to move WITH the scrollbar if that makes sense.

On mobile it does not work correctly because I can't scroll the lightbox up and down and see all of it's content.

I know I have "position: fixed;" in my CSS...

```
.ezmodal-container {
background: #fff;
padding: 0;
font-size: 14px;
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
z-index: 90001;
border: 2px solid #b01b11;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.8);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.8);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.8);
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%); 
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
        transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
```

...but if I remove it then the whole thing is out of alignment.

Here is my HTML code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mymsaa.org/wp-content/themes/dw-focus/assets/js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript</noscript>   
<script src="http://mymsaa.org/lightbox_test/src/ezmodal.js"></script>
<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript</noscript>          
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mymsaa.org/lightbox_test/src/ezmodal.css">

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!--LIGHTBOX-->      

<div class="ezmodal" ezmodal-autoopen="true">
<div class="ezmodal-container">

<!--IFRAME FORM-->                                            
<div id='subscribe_popup' style='overflow: hidden; overflow-y:hidden;'>
<div style="padding: 10px;">
<iframe src="http://mymsaa.org/wp-content/themes/dw-focus/video_register/iframe/iframe.php" border="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" name="pop"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
<!--IFRAME FORM--> 

<div class="ezmodal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn1" data-dismiss="ezmodal">Skip Registration</button>
</div>

</div>
</div>

<!--IFRAME CSS-->
<style type="text/css">

#subscribe_popup { width: 470px; height: 380px; overflow: hidden; overflow-y:hidden; }

#subscribe_popup iframe { width: 446px; height: 380px; }

/*992px*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1200px) {

#subscribe_popup { width: 470px;}
}

/*768px*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {

#subscribe_popup { width: 470px;}

}

/*480px*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 768px) {

#subscribe_popup { width: 280px; height: 420px; margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;}

#subscribe_popup iframe { width: 250px; height: 400px; }

}

/*320px*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {

#subscribe_popup { width: 280px; height: 420px; margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;}

#subscribe_popup iframe { width: 250px; height: 400px; }

}

</style>
<!--IFRAME CSS-->

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean scelerisque malesuada ligula, id cursus diam facilisis ac. Sed id pulvinar mauris. Phasellus ac arcu velit. Cras tempor vestibulum volutpat. Proin consectetur lectus elementum imperdiet congue. Quisque quis nunc libero. Praesent gravida urna metus, ut elementum arcu posuere quis. Suspendisse mattis, enim vitae semper porta, metus mauris dignissim lorem, non eleifend risus mauris non diam. Ut in ullamcorper tortor, eu lobortis nibh.    <p>

<p>Ut quis lectus sit amet tortor tempus imperdiet. Maecenas enim lacus, hendrerit ac volutpat quis, ornare eu diam. Maecenas nec odio odio. Aenean eu lectus lacinia, luctus mi non, placerat metus. Proin id tortor nec est suscipit ullamcorper sed eu metus. Donec efficitur, massa eu sagittis vehicula, magna erat gravida elit, dapibus vehicula tellus dolor sed purus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris auctor vel tellus vitae congue. Proin tincidunt quam velit, at posuere odio lobortis sit amet. Etiam posuere condimentum leo, a auctor elit sollicitudin nec. Vivamus faucibus tortor rhoncus orci fermentum, vitae efficitur orci mattis. Nunc est nunc, euismod vel magna vitae, fermentum dapibus libero. Maecenas quis erat aliquam enim scelerisque scelerisque sed vel metus. Sed eget finibus justo, consequat ornare sapien. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>     

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean scelerisque malesuada ligula, id cursus diam facilisis ac. Sed id pulvinar mauris. Phasellus ac arcu velit. Cras tempor vestibulum volutpat. Proin consectetur lectus elementum imperdiet congue. Quisque quis nunc libero. Praesent gravida urna metus, ut elementum arcu posuere quis. Suspendisse mattis, enim vitae semper porta, metus mauris dignissim lorem, non eleifend risus mauris non diam. Ut in ullamcorper tortor, eu lobortis nibh.    <p>

<p>Ut quis lectus sit amet tortor tempus imperdiet. Maecenas enim lacus, hendrerit ac volutpat quis, ornare eu diam. Maecenas nec odio odio. Aenean eu lectus lacinia, luctus mi non, placerat metus. Proin id tortor nec est suscipit ullamcorper sed eu metus. Donec efficitur, massa eu sagittis vehicula, magna erat gravida elit, dapibus vehicula tellus dolor sed purus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris auctor vel tellus vitae congue. Proin tincidunt quam velit, at posuere odio lobortis sit amet. Etiam posuere condimentum leo, a auctor elit sollicitudin nec. Vivamus faucibus tortor rhoncus orci fermentum, vitae efficitur orci mattis. Nunc est nunc, euismod vel magna vitae, fermentum dapibus libero. Maecenas quis erat aliquam enim scelerisque scelerisque sed vel metus. Sed eget finibus justo, consequat ornare sapien. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>  


<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean scelerisque malesuada ligula, id cursus diam facilisis ac. Sed id pulvinar mauris. Phasellus ac arcu velit. Cras tempor vestibulum volutpat. Proin consectetur lectus elementum imperdiet congue. Quisque quis nunc libero. Praesent gravida urna metus, ut elementum arcu posuere quis. Suspendisse mattis, enim vitae semper porta, metus mauris dignissim lorem, non eleifend risus mauris non diam. Ut in ullamcorper tortor, eu lobortis nibh.    <p>

<p>Ut quis lectus sit amet tortor tempus imperdiet. Maecenas enim lacus, hendrerit ac volutpat quis, ornare eu diam. Maecenas nec odio odio. Aenean eu lectus lacinia, luctus mi non, placerat metus. Proin id tortor nec est suscipit ullamcorper sed eu metus. Donec efficitur, massa eu sagittis vehicula, magna erat gravida elit, dapibus vehicula tellus dolor sed purus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris auctor vel tellus vitae congue. Proin tincidunt quam velit, at posuere odio lobortis sit amet. Etiam posuere condimentum leo, a auctor elit sollicitudin nec. Vivamus faucibus tortor rhoncus orci fermentum, vitae efficitur orci mattis. Nunc est nunc, euismod vel magna vitae, fermentum dapibus libero. Maecenas quis erat aliquam enim scelerisque scelerisque sed vel metus. Sed eget finibus justo, consequat ornare sapien. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>  

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean scelerisque malesuada ligula, id cursus diam facilisis ac. Sed id pulvinar mauris. Phasellus ac arcu velit. Cras tempor vestibulum volutpat. Proin consectetur lectus elementum imperdiet congue. Quisque quis nunc libero. Praesent gravida urna metus, ut elementum arcu posuere quis. Suspendisse mattis, enim vitae semper porta, metus mauris dignissim lorem, non eleifend risus mauris non diam. Ut in ullamcorper tortor, eu lobortis nibh.    <p>

<p>Ut quis lectus sit amet tortor tempus imperdiet. Maecenas enim lacus, hendrerit ac volutpat quis, ornare eu diam. Maecenas nec odio odio. Aenean eu lectus lacinia, luctus mi non, placerat metus. Proin id tortor nec est suscipit ullamcorper sed eu metus. Donec efficitur, massa eu sagittis vehicula, magna erat gravida elit, dapibus vehicula tellus dolor sed purus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris auctor vel tellus vitae congue. Proin tincidunt quam velit, at posuere odio lobortis sit amet. Etiam posuere condimentum leo, a auctor elit sollicitudin nec. Vivamus faucibus tortor rhoncus orci fermentum, vitae efficitur orci mattis. Nunc est nunc, euismod vel magna vitae, fermentum dapibus libero. Maecenas quis erat aliquam enim scelerisque scelerisque sed vel metus. Sed eget finibus justo, consequat ornare sapien. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>  
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean scelerisque malesuada ligula, id cursus diam facilisis ac. Sed id pulvinar mauris. Phasellus ac arcu velit. Cras tempor vestibulum volutpat. Proin consectetur lectus elementum imperdiet congue. Quisque quis nunc libero. Praesent gravida urna metus, ut elementum arcu posuere quis. Suspendisse mattis, enim vitae semper porta, metus mauris dignissim lorem, non eleifend risus mauris non diam. Ut in ullamcorper tortor, eu lobortis nibh.    <p>

<p>Ut quis lectus sit amet tortor tempus imperdiet. Maecenas enim lacus, hendrerit ac volutpat quis, ornare eu diam. Maecenas nec odio odio. Aenean eu lectus lacinia, luctus mi non, placerat metus. Proin id tortor nec est suscipit ullamcorper sed eu metus. Donec efficitur, massa eu sagittis vehicula, magna erat gravida elit, dapibus vehicula tellus dolor sed purus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris auctor vel tellus vitae congue. Proin tincidunt quam velit, at posuere odio lobortis sit amet. Etiam posuere condimentum leo, a auctor elit sollicitudin nec. Vivamus faucibus tortor rhoncus orci fermentum, vitae efficitur orci mattis. Nunc est nunc, euismod vel magna vitae, fermentum dapibus libero. Maecenas quis erat aliquam enim scelerisque scelerisque sed vel metus. Sed eget finibus justo, consequat ornare sapien. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>  
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean scelerisque malesuada ligula, id cursus diam facilisis ac. Sed id pulvinar mauris. Phasellus ac arcu velit. Cras tempor vestibulum volutpat. Proin consectetur lectus elementum imperdiet congue. Quisque quis nunc libero. Praesent gravida urna metus, ut elementum arcu posuere quis. Suspendisse mattis, enim vitae semper porta, metus mauris dignissim lorem, non eleifend risus mauris non diam. Ut in ullamcorper tortor, eu lobortis nibh.    <p>

<p>Ut quis lectus sit amet tortor tempus imperdiet. Maecenas enim lacus, hendrerit ac volutpat quis, ornare eu diam. Maecenas nec odio odio. Aenean eu lectus lacinia, luctus mi non, placerat metus. Proin id tortor nec est suscipit ullamcorper sed eu metus. Donec efficitur, massa eu sagittis vehicula, magna erat gravida elit, dapibus vehicula tellus dolor sed purus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris auctor vel tellus vitae congue. Proin tincidunt quam velit, at posuere odio lobortis sit amet. Etiam posuere condimentum leo, a auctor elit sollicitudin nec. Vivamus faucibus tortor rhoncus orci fermentum, vitae efficitur orci mattis. Nunc est nunc, euismod vel magna vitae, fermentum dapibus libero. Maecenas quis erat aliquam enim scelerisque scelerisque sed vel metus. Sed eget finibus justo, consequat ornare sapien. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>  
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean scelerisque malesuada ligula, id cursus diam facilisis ac. Sed id pulvinar mauris. Phasellus ac arcu velit. Cras tempor vestibulum volutpat. Proin consectetur lectus elementum imperdiet congue. Quisque quis nunc libero. Praesent gravida urna metus, ut elementum arcu posuere quis. Suspendisse mattis, enim vitae semper porta, metus mauris dignissim lorem, non eleifend risus mauris non diam. Ut in ullamcorper tortor, eu lobortis nibh.    <p>

<p>Ut quis lectus sit amet tortor tempus imperdiet. Maecenas enim lacus, hendrerit ac volutpat quis, ornare eu diam. Maecenas nec odio odio. Aenean eu lectus lacinia, luctus mi non, placerat metus. Proin id tortor nec est suscipit ullamcorper sed eu metus. Donec efficitur, massa eu sagittis vehicula, magna erat gravida elit, dapibus vehicula tellus dolor sed purus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris auctor vel tellus vitae congue. Proin tincidunt quam velit, at posuere odio lobortis sit amet. Etiam posuere condimentum leo, a auctor elit sollicitudin nec. Vivamus faucibus tortor rhoncus orci fermentum, vitae efficitur orci mattis. Nunc est nunc, euismod vel magna vitae, fermentum dapibus libero. Maecenas quis erat aliquam enim scelerisque scelerisque sed vel metus. Sed eget finibus justo, consequat ornare sapien. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>  
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean scelerisque malesuada ligula, id cursus diam facilisis ac. Sed id pulvinar mauris. Phasellus ac arcu velit. Cras tempor vestibulum volutpat. Proin consectetur lectus elementum imperdiet congue. Quisque quis nunc libero. Praesent gravida urna metus, ut elementum arcu posuere quis. Suspendisse mattis, enim vitae semper porta, metus mauris dignissim lorem, non eleifend risus mauris non diam. Ut in ullamcorper tortor, eu lobortis nibh.    <p>
```

Here is my CSS.

```
/*
* eZmodal
* doc: http://markusslima    .github    .io/ezmodal/
* github: https://github    .com/markusslima/ezmodal
*
* Copyright (c) 2015 Markus Vinicius da Silva Lima
* Version 0    .1    .2
* Licensed under the MIT license    .
*/
.ezmodal {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
z-index: 90000;
background: rgba(0,0,0,    .6);
overflow-x: visible;
overflow-y: visible;
display: none;
}

.ezmodal-container {

background: #fff;
padding: 0;
font-size: 14px;
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
z-index: 90001;
border: 2px solid #b01b11;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0    .8);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0    .8);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0    .8);
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%); 
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
        transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}



.ezmodal     .ezmodal-close:hover {
color: #535353;
}

.ezmodal     .ezmodal-header {

}

.ezmodal     .ezmodal-content {

}

.ezmodal     .ezmodal-footer {
padding: 10px 20px;
border-top: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
text-align: center;

}
```

Comment: you can set instead absolute position, and via javascript set the height of overlay tall like the document.

Comment: Could you show me an example of the javascript please?

Comment: I posted an example in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `.ezmodal` in position `absolute`.

and set the div height like the document with this script:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

 function docuHeight() {
 var wH = $(window).height();
 var bH = window.innerHeight;

jQuery('.ezmodal').css({
  height: wH
});
jQuery('.ezmodal-container').css({
  top: bH/2
});
 }
 docuHeight(); 
  $( window ).resize(function() {
docuHeight();  
 });


});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you but now the black overlay behind the lightbox is cut off, how can I get the black overlay to be the height of the document also?